# Reboot and select proper boot device

Tags: windows-7

My computer started rebooting when ever it would come up to the windows screen or otherwise would just never load. So I reinstalled windows. Three days later I boot it up and it says Reboot and select proper boot device. So I checked the bios and it has the hdd as the first boot option. When I restarted it came up with the option for safe mode or normal, either one I chose it would begin loading and than reboot to give same message. I reinstalled windows and it ran fine for three days, after I booted it up a second time windows ran slow, so I restarted and again it's having the same issue with it saying Reboot and select proper boot device.

OS: windows 7 home ultimate.
Ram: 3 gb
Hdd: sata 500gb
Processor: pentium core duo 2.0 ghz

Comment: start using another operating system, like Ubuntu

Comment: If you reinstall the windows now first of all run the `cmd` and run a `chkdsk /f` may be it will fix your problem. Also don't install anything on HDD just install the MS-Essential and scan for the virus with latest update.

Comment: It won't let me boot up in general. I've attempted safe mode, safe mode with networking, and with command. I even tried last known good configuration. It all does the same thing begins to load and reboots to say reboot and select proper boot device.  A friend gave me another hard drive so I am going to swap them out and see if that corrects issue. I will post the results. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: smells like a failing hard-drive...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there could potentially be a problem on the disk.  I would suggest properly testing the Hard Drive to ensure it isn't failing.

There are a variety of bootable disk utilities to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/index-files/simpletech-legacy-downloads#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.